# reproducing grep "my pattern" myfile.log | sort | uniq | wc -l in awk

Tags: awk, mingw

If I perform this grep on my target file I get eg 275 as result.

But I want to learn awk so tried this in awk:

```
 awk 'BEGIN { count=0 } /my pattern/ { count++ } END { print count }' myfile.log
```

And this prints the 275 as expected.

So getting ambitious I created an awk script like this:

```
BEGIN { 
   print "Log File Analysis";
   message=0;
   events=0;
}

{
  /message/  {  messages++;  }
  /event/    { events++;  }
}
END { 
  print "messages:\t" messages;
  print "events:\t" events;
}
```

I get a syntax error,

```
$ awk -f test_learn.awk test_log.log
awk: test_learn.awk:16:   /message/  {  messages++;  }
awk: test_learn.awk:16:              ^ syntax error
```

What am I doing wrong?

I am using awk from MinGW shell on windows 7.

Comment: I think you've got an extra `'` in there. Therefore `/event/    { events++'  }` should be `/event/    { events++;  }`

Comment: Sorry, that was a paste error into SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
 awk 'BEGIN { count=0 }; /my pattern/{count++ }; END { print count }' myfile.log
```

OR

```
awk 'BEGIN { count=0};  { if ($0 ~ /my pattern/)  count++ }; END { print count };' myfile.log
```

Better yet, as variables are initialized as zero by default, you don't need the BEGIN block, so

```
awk '/my pattern/{count++ }; END { print count };' myfile.log
```

You can either have a default loop applied to all lines in a file, as in 2d example with the if, or you can have multiple blocks, "filtered" by pattern, as above, and in your edited addition.

When doing one-liners have you have, some awks required the semi-colon to separate the BEGIN and END blocks from the main loop block.

**Edit**

Same Idea with your 2nd issue, and integrating Ed Morton's improvments (thanks)

```
/message/  {  messages++  }
/event/    { events++  }

END { 
 print "Log File Analysis"
 print "messages:\t" messages
  print "events:\t" events
}
```

IHTH

Comment: oh ok.  I thought you had to have {} around code block.  But it seems you can have multiple {} in "code block"

Comment: either 1 code block (besides BEGIN/ENDs) with `if (var ~ /pat/){...}` or multiple pattern matching blocks. Actually you can have both, but the pattern matching blocks can't be inside a default block `{ ... }`. Good luck.

Comment: Note that you don't need to init numeric awk variables to zero, awk does that for you, and you don't need/want all the trailing semi-colons as awk statements end at the end of lines. Also, move the first print to the start of the END block, and you don't need the BEGIN block at all.

Comment: @EdMorton : Thanks, you're right, good to reinforce that awk doesn't require variables initialization. I've updated my answer now. I was in a rush, user619818 had posted just the first part which I answered. Then the 2nd part appeared, so I quickly fixed that.

Comment: you could also get rid of those null statements (trailing semi-colons) and the `'` after events++ ...

Comment: you're welcome. wrt to your statement that "some awks required the semi-colon to separate the BEGIN and END blocks from the main loop block". I've never come across that in any awk - do you have one in mind that behaves that way?

Comment: The old Sun awk and nawk had this problem. Hm.. maybe it was just the original awk. Also the NeXT awk, and ironically for such a high-end platform (at the time), no nawk version compatible was available. Long time ago. Good luck to all.